# textAlign Property in HTML5 Canvas not working properly in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make javascript fill text inside canvas and I want it to be center aligned, it is working well in Chrome and Firefox but behaving weirdly in IE, here is the code

```
    ctx.drawImage(background,space,0,500,500);

    ctx.fillStyle="#FFF";
    ctx.font="40px Droid Arabic Kufi";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.direction = 'rtl';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';          
    if (x == '') {x = 'شعورك تجاه بيتك سيظهر هنا'}
    firstLineHeight = wrapText(ctx, x, 250, 200, 400, lineHeight);
    ctx.font="20px Droid Arabic Kufi";
    if (ss == '') {sss = 'من: اسمك سيظهر هنا'}
    else {sss = 'من: ' +  ss}
    wrapText(ctx, sss, 250, 250+((firstLineHeight-1)*30), 400, lineHeight);



    function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {

    var words = text.split(' ');
    var line = '';
    linesCount = 1;   
    for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
            context.fillText(line, x, y);
            line = words[n] + ' ';
            y += lineHeight;
            linesCount++;
        }
        else {
            line = testLine;
        }
    }

    context.fillText(line, x, y+10);
    return linesCount;

}
```

[Here is a link here](http://musakhalil.com/jotun-2/create/)

Edited (Screenshots):

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtYpT.png)

[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj2ky.png)

Comment: which version of IE you're checking in?

Comment: it looks fine to me..can you be more specific. You can always show us a screenshot marking the concerned part.

Comment: @sam100rav I mentioned a link there and now I am gonna upload 2 screenshots. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" dir="rtl"></canvas>
```

use `dir="rtl"` directly in canvas element..

Comment: I had to force it to stay LTR

   
    `<canvas id="myCanvas" dir="ltr"></canvas>`